# Issue in infowindow content pagination using google API's datatable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, pagination, infowindow

I am new to google map. I need an help to implement pagination for the table content inside infowindow while clicking marker.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table']});
    var map;
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
    var mapInfos = [];
    var infoWindowView = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    function initialize()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
                zoom:5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.072086992455475,-5.05078125),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myCenter
                    });
        marker.setMap(map);

        function mapInfoTable(container)
        {
           this.tableContainer = container;
            var me = this;
            var cssClass = {rowNumberCell: 'rowNumberCellClass'};

            this.dT = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            this.dT.addColumn("string", "Name");   
            this.dT.addColumn("string", "City");                 


            this.populateTable = function()
            {
              this.dT.addRows([
                            ['A1' ,'C1'],
                            ['A2' ,'C2'],
                            ['A3' ,'C3'],
                            ['A4' ,'C4'],
                            ['A5' ,'C5'],
                            ['A6' ,'C6'],
                            ['A7' ,'C7'],
                            ['A8' ,'C8']
                          ]);
               this.draw();
            }
            this.table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(this.tableContainer));

            this.draw = function()
            {
                this.table.draw(this.dT, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true, cssClassNames: cssClass, page: 'enable', pageSize : 4, pagingSymbols: {prev: 'Previous',next: 'Next'}});
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
                    var InfoTab = new mapInfoTable('TableInfo');
                    InfoTab.populateTable(mapInfos);
                    var content = document.getElementById("TableInfo").innerHTML;
                    infoWindowView.setContent(content);
                    infoWindowView.open(map, this);
                });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

 </head>
 <body>
<div id="mapCanvas" style="width:800px;height:500px"></div>
<div id="TableInfo" style="position:fixed;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the 'domready' event on the infowindow before populating the table.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q8qepb9n/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['table']
});
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
var mapInfos = [];
var infoWindowView = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.072086992455475, -5.05078125),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter
  });
  marker.setMap(map);

  function mapInfoTable(container) {
    this.tableContainer = container;
    var me = this;
    var cssClass = {
      rowNumberCell: 'rowNumberCellClass'
    };

    this.dT = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    this.dT.addColumn("string", "Name");
    this.dT.addColumn("string", "City");


    this.populateTable = function() {
      this.dT.addRows([
        ['A1', 'C1'],
        ['A2', 'C2'],
        ['A3', 'C3'],
        ['A4', 'C4'],
        ['A5', 'C5'],
        ['A6', 'C6'],
        ['A7', 'C7'],
        ['A8', 'C8']
      ]);
      this.draw();
    }
    this.table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(this.tableContainer));

    this.draw = function() {
      this.table.draw(this.dT, {
        allowHtml: true,
        showRowNumber: true,
        cssClassNames: cssClass,
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 4,
        pagingSymbols: {
          prev: 'Previous',
          next: 'Next'
        }
      });
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    var dTableInfo = document.createElement("div");
    dTableInfo.id = "dTableInfo";
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindowView, 'domready', function() {

      var InfoTab = new mapInfoTable('dTableInfo');
      InfoTab.populateTable(mapInfos);
    });
    infoWindowView.setContent(dTableInfo);
    infoWindowView.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapCanvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: I have another doubt in cluster marker i.e when i am trying to click cluster icon it is not showing infowindow instead it is zooming into map. But when i am using mouseover event it is working fine. Why this happens and how to resolve this ?

Comment: Hi... from above snippet whenever marker is clicked the infowindow opens with some blur or shaking like UI . You can see that clearly in 'mouseover' event. Can u explain me why this is happen... please ?

Comment: I don't see that (in Chrome).

Comment: Please try it in firefox with mouseover event

Comment: Don't see it there either.  In any case, that is a different question.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your great answers.